NumPy imports a module then immediately does an `import *` from the module - What is the intention for having both?
Question
I have seen this recurring pattern in the NumPy source's __init__.py modules and am confused what the purpose of having both lines. After doing some more understanding of how importing works, it seems that the same module is being imported into the current namespace AND the module's namespace.
Below is an example:
NumPy Source code v.1.26.x
## Source: snippet from "numpy/core/__init__.py" v.1.26.x

from . import numeric     # {1} Importing the contents of `numeric.py` into the `numeric` namespace.
from .numeric import *    # {2} Importing the contents of `numeric.py` into the current namespace.

What is the reasoning for importing the same thing into two different namespaces? Or, am I misunderstanding what it is doing?
What I've tried
I've verified a function that is being imported in this manner and confirmed that the same function is available in both namespaces.
import numpy  # Tested on numpy v.1.26.x

## {1} - The function `zeros()` is available in the `core` namespace.
numpy.core.zeros((3, 2))  # Outputs: 3x2 2D array of zeros.

## {2} - The function `zeros()` is available in the current namespace.
numpy.zeros((3, 2))       # Outputs: 3x2 2D array of zeros.



Backwards compatibility, maybe? Searching GitHub, there are apparently 1.1 thousand uses of "np.core.numeric." https://github.com/search?q=%22np.core.numeric%22&type=code

The obvious answer to "why import the same thing into two different namespaces" is to have the "thing" in both namespaces. Backward compatibility certainly makes sense ... along with its corollary it will be broken otherwise.

It doesn't require more memory or time.
